# Условное переопредлеение метода

Tags: c++, c++17

Возможно ли, в рамках С++17|20 компактно записать условную реализацию метода базового класса?
Не компилируемый пример:

```
struct S1
{
    virtual int func1() { return 10; }
};
struct S2
{
    virtual int func2() { return 20; }
};

template<typename Base>
struct Wrap : Base
{
    static constexpr bool has_func1 = std::is_same< Base, S1 >::value;
    static constexpr bool has_func2 = std::is_same< Base, S2 >::value;

    requires has_func1 // Не работает, поскольку func1 - не шаблонная функция
    int  func1() override { return Base::func1() +1; }

    std::enable_if_t<has_func2, int>  // дает ошибку компиляции, если has_func2==false
    func2() override { return Base::func2() +1; }
};

Wrap<S1> instance;
Wrap<S2> instance;
```

Понимаю, что есть с++11 - решение со специализацией класса, в зависимости от флага:

```
template<typename Base, bool has_func1 = std::is_same< Base, S1 >::value >
struct SpecialWrap;

template<typename Base>
struct SpecialWrap<Base, true> : Base
{
    int  func1() override { return Base::func1() +1; }
};
template<typename Base>
struct SpecialWrap<Base, false> : Base
{};

template<typename Base>
struct Wrap : SpecialWrap< Base >
{
   ...
};
```

Но получается уж очень многословно, особенно, если нужно учесть несколько условий.

Comment: А что Вы на самом деле хотите сделать? Добавьте в `Wrap` член-функцию, которая будет проверять тип `Base` и, в зависимости от его типа, вызывать нужную функцию.

Comment: Оффтоп: когда мне хочется сделать нечто подобное, я сразу думаю о том, что у меня просто "кривой" дизайн. Это про исходную формулировку вопроса с условной реализацией.

Comment: Наследование хороша тогда, когда сущности логически связаны. Смешивать полиморфизм времени компиляции и времени выполнения, мягко говоря, не желательная практика.  Если есть наследование, используйте какой нибудь https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns . Тут просто добавить абстрактный базовый класс....

Answer (score 0):

Я уже написал в комментарии свой взгляд на это и полностью поддерживаю мнение `isnullxbh` в комментариях. Но если нужно, то я бы сделал что то типа:

```
struct B {
    virtual int func() = 0;    
};
struct S1 : B
{   
    virtual int func() override { return func1(); }
private:
    int func1() { return 10; }
};
struct S2 : B
{    
    virtual int func() override { return func2(); }
private:
    int func2() { return 20; }
};

template<typename Base>
struct Wrap : Base{ };

Wrap<S1> w1; Wrap<S2> w2;
```